# Pass php array from form to javascript file

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have a php associative array $php_array. Also, I have a form like below in my php file.

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <p class="submit">
        <input name="submit" class="button-primary" value="Send" type="submit" id="">
        <input type="hidden" name="details" value="' . $php_array . '"/>
    </p>
</form>
```

I want to pass this array $php_array to a javascript file like

```
  `details = $("input[name=details]").val();`
```

The array is in the form

```
Array(
    [59] => Sree
    [53] => Smith
)
```

I want to display the names as drop down using javascript on clicking the link 'send'. how can I pass the php array to javascript

Comment: you will need to encode your array into json format, then decode that json from the client side and parse you decoded array from javascript;

Answer (score 2):

You should encode your php array into json format, then decode it from client side;

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <p class="submit">
        <input name="submit" class="button-primary" value="Send" type="submit" id="">
        <input type="hidden" name="details" value='<?php echo json_encode($php_array); ?>'/>
    </p>
</form>
```

and from your javascript file :

```
var details = JSON && JSON.parse($("input[name=details]").val()) || $.parseJSON($("input[name=details]").val());
```

Comment: I tried the same code but I'm getting the following error.
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input(…)

Comment: this means that your json is invalid , check the validity of it

Comment: Im getting the json encoded value asthis in php file.`{"59":"Sree","53":"Smith"}` on passing the same to js im getting that error

Comment: and update this code : `value="<?php echo json_encode($php_array); ?>"` by `value='<?php echo json_encode($php_array); ?>'`

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear your end goal, is it posting via XHR (ajax)?

In that case I think using the form to pass the data is not required. You could just encode it to json and grab it on you JS file or block like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var details = <?php print(json_encode($php_array)) ?>;

  // using jQuery
  $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    // use 'details' here as you need
    return false;
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply encode your variable to json using `json_encode($php_array)` then in the JavaScript side parse it back using `JSON.parse()`